# Java : Replace id's(manually created) which are inside HTML tags

Tags: java, html, regex, string, replace

I am working on a Java application in which for one of the functionality, we needed to add ID's inside the text, which user is inputs from the front-end.

Example (Self-written):

```
<list id="cke-1234-345">
//List elements
</list>

<p id="cke-345-456">Hello world</p>
```

Now the problem is, these ID's are unique and not necessary in the backend, where we do text-comparison. What I would like to do is to remove the `id="cke*"` for all of them.

*Note* : All Id's start with `cke`.

**I know how to replace all the HTML tags, but I only want to remove the `id="cke*` from inside.**

Can anyone help me out with this. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: Can someone explain me why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer comes with the strong caveat that [you should not use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3788176). Use a proper HTML parsing library.*

You might be able to use the following regular expression:

```
hackyCleanedString = str.replaceAll("\\s*id=\"cke[^\">]*\"", "");
```

However, there are likely many corner cases (or even non corner-cases) which will not be handled correctly, e.g. the string appearing in a text node.

Comment: I am getting Illegal escape character in string literal, which one its not shown.

Comment: Thanks. Trying. Just gimme a moment my friend.. :D